# Free Group where generators aren't just one symbol?

Tags: gap, combinatorial-group-theory

The question is:

Show that $G = \langle a, b, c \mid a^2bacacab \rangle$ is a free group on the free generators $ab$ and $ac$.

This is in section 1.4, page 39 of Combinatorial Group Theory by Magnus, Karass, and Solitar (standard graduate text on the subject), where it is mentioned but not proved or given as an exercise.

I can see by straightforwardly manipulating this relator that indeed $a$, $b$, and $c$ can each be expressed as a product of $ab$, $ac$, and their inverses (for example, c = abacacabac).

However,

1. How do I make sense of "the free group on $ab$ and $ac$." Does this mean that $G$ is isomorphic to $\langle d,e \rangle$ under the rewriting rule $ab \to d$, $ac \to e$? This needs to be proved separately, no?
2. Why should the free group on $ab$ and $ac$ satisfy $G$'s relator?

If it helps,
I tried the following on GAP:

```
F := FreeGroup(3);
a := F.1;
b := F.2;
c := F.3;
G := F/[(a^2)*b*a*c*a*c*a*b];
StructureDescription(G);
    Error, no method found!
IsFreeGroup(G);
    false
```

So structure description doesn't work here, and it says it's NOT a free group? Maybe that's just a technicality where `IsFreeGroup(G)` only tells you if `G` was entered exactly as a free group.

Please let me know if you can help me with any of the above, or just give me an independent proof without reference to what I've written about my progress thus far. Thank you.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez yes, I don't know how to make the asterisks show up, but indeed I entered it correctly in GAP, though it doesn't work for this presentation.

Comment: It means that your group is isomorphic to $F_2$, say with generators $x,y$, via the isomorphism $x \mapsto ab$ and $y \mapsto ac$. In other words, $ab$ and $ac$ generate your group with no nontrivial relations.

Comment: `IsFreeGroup` in GAP is not a freeness test, but simply the category that a group was created as `FreeGroup`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x$ and $y$ are elements of a group $G$, then when we say $G$ is free on $x$ and $y$, we mean that the unique homomorphism from the free group on indeterminates $X$ and $Y$ that maps $X$ to $x$ and $Y$ to $y$ is an isomorphism.

The relator tells you that $a(ab)(ac)^2(ab) = 1$ so that $a = ((ab)(ac)^2(ab))^{-1}$. So you you can write $a$ as $(xy^2x)^{-1}$, where $x = ab$ and $y = ac$ and so eliminate $a$ from a  presentation of $G$ in terms of $a$, $x$ and $y$. Can you take it from there?

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I don't know how to actually show this for this group on $ab$ and $ac$, however.

Comment: I've added a bit more about what the relator tells you. I hope you can  take it from there.

Answer (score 1):

I see it now. Thank you for clarifications from others.

$\langle a,b,c|a^2bacacab \rangle \cong \langle a,b,c,d,e|d=ab, e=ac, a^{-1} = de^2d \rangle \cong \langle a,b,c,d,e | b=de^2d^2, c=de^2de, a^{-1} = de^2d \rangle \cong \langle <d,e|>\rangle$

which shows that indeed $ab$ and $ac$ make a free group, as well as the original question that this is isomorphic to G.